# Accessing item from an other item in Google App Maker

Tags: google-apps-script, google-app-maker

I'm trying to achieve a wall-like view using Accordion. I have items that have a date and I would like to achieve this display :

```
TODAY
Item A
Item B
Item C

THIS WEEK
Item D
Item E

PAST
Item F
Item G
```

I used Accordion List to successfully display all my days with their dates:

```
Date A
Item A

Date B
Item B

...
```

I would like now to display **Date B** only if **Date B** <> **Date A** so that I can achieve a grouping by date. The previous example becomes:

```
Date A
Item A
Item B
```

But I can't figure out how to reach the value of **Date A** from **Date B** as they are in different items.

I tried with itemIndex but I can't manage to get the previous value. [Google App Maker doc](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/ui/layout-widgets#accordion) says that:

> The accordion is a ListPanel with a detailed view that expands below the selected row. This detailed view is edited as a prototype, like the main row view. During runtime, one row is shown per item in the accordion's datasource. The datasource for that row is a special single item datasource pointing to the corresponding item in the Accordion's datasource. The detail row is also given this special datasource. This allows the prototype row to access the current row's item with the '@datasource.item' syntax.

But I can't get to navigate trough the item list at all. Any thought?

Comment: You may try to create a relational database with 1 date to many items.

Comment: I can't because I use calculated models and they don't accept relations...